# c# 2 Dimension Array Random Numbers

Tags: c#, arrays

So I need to make 2 Dimension Array with random numbers, and expel the numbers like in multiplication table. It should look like this:
[image]

My code for now looks like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
int[,] array = new int[10, 10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        array[i, j] = random.Next();
        Console.Write("\t{0}\t{1}" ,i,j);
    }
```

EDIT:::This worked for me!

```
        Random random = new Random();
        int[,] array = new int[10, 10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                array[i, j] = random.Next(10);
                Console.Write(array[i,j]+"\t");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n");
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: May we see the rest of your code? You'l need a Console.WriteLine(); right after the second for loop to break into next line.

Comment: The issue is, that i don't get 10x10 but there are more numbers.

Comment: Well you are printing the coordinates instead of the numbers themselves, so of course there's more of them

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by `expel the numbers like in multiplication table`. Are you sure "expel" is the English word you were looking for - or did you perhaps mean "output" or "print"

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by ThatBrianDude

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Random random = new Random();

      int[,] array = new int[10, 10];

      for (int i = 0;
           i < 10;
           i++)
      {

        for (int j = 0;
             j < 10;
             j++)
        {
          array[i,
                j] = random.Next();
          Console.Write("\t{0}",
                        array[i,
                              j]);
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
      }
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A 10x10 array of random numbers could be generated like this:

```
var rnd = new Random();

var randomArray = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(x => {
    return Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(y => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
}).ToArray();
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/GWTAK54347

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should work for you:

```
private static void RunArrayCode()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[,] array = new int[10, 10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                array[i, j] = random.Next();

                // No tabs if it's the first item in a row
                Console.Write("{0}{1}\t{2}", (j == 0 ? "" : "\t"), i, j);
            }

            // Each new row goes on its own line
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```